# Cargar datos relacionados de 2 tabla en una vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Disculpen la molestia, espero me puedan ayudar. Si tengo una tabla Persona Juricdia y otra tabla Entidad Bancaria de que manera puedo mostrar los datos de ambas tablas en una vista? Intente con with pero no me regresa ningun dato

CONTROLLER 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MODELO PERSONAS JURIDICAS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MODELO ENTIDAD BANCARIA 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RESPUESTA DEL DD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y pega el código como texto en lugar de usar imágenes. Lee [como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te des una idea de como funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas agregar los nombres de las llaves foraneas y locales en tus relaciones. Creo que no estás usando el nombre por default que es **id**

EntidadBancaria

```
return $this->hasMany(PersonaJuridica::class,"id","entidadBancaria_id");
```

PersonaJuridica

```
return $this->belongsTo(EntidadBancaria::class,"entidadBancaria_id","id");
```

Según la documentación, tienes que seguir el siguiente constructor:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key');
```

Comment: Lo ideal es no responder a las preguntas hasta que el OP siga las normas del sitio. En este caso el OP no ha puesto el código como texto sino como imagen.